# How to replace the first letter of a word in a sentence with the first letter of the next word?

Tags: python

I want to write a function that replaces the first letter of a word in a sentence with the first letter of the next word (the last word gets the first letter of the first word).
I was able to make a list that contains every word in the sentence but I couldn't swap the letters, I tried to do it with for loop but I just couldn't figure it how.

Comment: Welcome! Have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What code did you write? What exactly was wrong with the output? Share what you did and people will help.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow. People here are nice and helpful, but expect users to put some effort, not ask for their work to be done. Read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not private tutorial service, nor intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation — and that is where you should be looking for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this code is understandable for you.

```python3
sentence = "Hello world! Foo bar baz"
words = sentence.split(" ")

result = []
for i in range(len(words)):
    # The first letter of the next word
    # `i + 1` is the index of the next word
    # `% len(words)` causes it to loop back to the start if it would reach off the end of the list
    letter = words[i + 1 % len(words)][0]

    # This word except for its first letter. `[1:]` is a slice, meaning "everything from index 1 onwards".
    remainder = words[i][1:]
    
    result.append(letter + remainder)

# `" ".join(...)` concatenates the list back into a string
result_string = "".join(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's code in Python that splits the sentence into a list and then creates a new string with each word having the first letter of the next word.

```
def replaceFirstLetters(sentence):
    # Split the sentence into list words
    sentenceList = sentence.split()
    # Create string where the new string will be stored
    newSentence = ""
    # Loop through the list of words (except for the last one)
    for i in range(len(sentenceList)-1):
        # Replace the first letter of the word with the first letter of the last word and add a space
        # sentenceList[i+1] is the next word and sentenceList[i+1][0] is the first letter of the next word
        # sentenceList[i] is the current word and sentenceList[i][1:] is the rest of the word (without the first letter)
        newSentence += sentenceList[i+1][0] + sentenceList[i][1:] + " "
    # Add the last word to the new string with the first letter of the first word
    newSentence += sentenceList[0][0] + sentenceList[-1][1:]
    # Return the new string
    return newSentence
```